# Eclipse (Kepler) runs every new JUnit test with JUnit3 runner instead of Junit4 runner

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, junit

When I create a JUnit test and run it with Run As->JUnit test, Eclipse always wants to run the test with JUnit3 runner. I always have to go to Run Configuration then and manually set the current test to JUnit4 runner. This is absolutely annoying. I always get...

> No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 3';

Indeed, it's an Android Maven project, and maybe Eclipse got some wrong information about running test within the project (since Android uses JUnit 3), but actually it doesn't matter if it's an Android project and there is nothing configured for JUnit 3, no Maven config, no build path config. It's always JUnit4.

I run a plain Junit4 test not on Android, so why does Eclipse always think to run the test with JUnit3? And where can I default it to JUnit4? The build path of the project contains JUnit 4.8.2 as well. I didn't find any Eclipse configuration which could cause this and I can't set a common run configuration for all tests since every JUnit test has its own run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I upgraded to Luna where the problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

That is no problem to fix.  I've been using Maven on Eclipse for years and never noticed the issue you are experiencing.  If you are using Eclipse "Luna", the "Java Developer" version, then you can convert your project to a Maven project.  Once it is converted to Maven, just add the JUnit 4.11 dependency to your project and then use Maven to refresh/rebuild the project dependencies.   Then, after Maven has rebuilt the dependencies, just go into your project settings for "Build Path" and remove the Junit 3 library, if it shows up in there.

So, using Maven, you have complete control of your dependencies.

Comment: I never had such problems before too. It's very strange, but it doesn't have anything to do with Maven. It's an Eclipse issue. Moreover, Eclipse seems to have problems with Android Maven dependencies. I need to add some libraries manually to the build path although this should be handled by plugin. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977715/eclipse-why-and-when-to-add-libraries-to-build-path-when-using-maven-project-to

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way.  I would have Maven include your local dependencies so that you dont need to touch the project dependencies in Eclipse.  You can do it using the Maven using the <scope>system</scope>  property along with the 'systemPath' property.

Comment: When some1 checks out a Maven project, the project must immediately be able to build, without tinkering around with local configurations or dependencies. Dependency management is exactly what Maven is for. And you can't imagine how often I saw such weird configurations in companies.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you.  If you need to include .jars in a local project 'libs' directory, then the maven 'system' scope is the nicest way to do that without causing configuration hell for others.